# how to send TG message with chat id from text file with python

Tags: python

I have chat_id that is saved in a text file, but I can't send msg but when I keep that chat_id in JSON file, all working files.

I want to send MSG with a text file, so how to send a message with a chat id saved in a text file.

```
client.start()
list_file = 'chatid.txt'
list = open(list_file, 'r').read().splitlines()
for chat in list :
    try :
        client.send_message(chat, message=(messagess))
        print(chat, ">> Message Send Success...")
        print( ">> Waiting for some Seconds...")
        time.sleep(random.randrange(60, 120))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GwyU.png)

Comment: Please be more specific. What framework/library are you using to send messages? What have you tried so far? I suppose TG stands for Telegram?

Comment: Have you tried removing the dashes at the beginning of each line? Currently, you're also reading them in.

Comment: yes i tried without dashes but not working
but work only with josn file not send with txt file

Comment: Could you maybe provide your whole code? There are many flaws and it's hard to tell what the actual problem could be. The code above misses variables, imports, and the try block is also not syntactically correct. Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
client.start()
with open('chatid.txt', "r") as file:
    for chatid in [chatid[1:] for chatid in file.readlines()]:
        try:
            client.send_message(chatid, message=(messagess))
            print(chatid, ">> Message Send Success...")
        except:
            print(chatid, "fail message here")

        print( ">> Waiting for some Seconds...")
        time.sleep(random.randrange(60, 120))
```